# Deleting resources managed by a vector

Tags: c++

I want a vector to hold pointers to some objects that it will own.

Here is the vector:

`private:
    std::vector<fppVirtual*> m_fapps;`

I have created elements like this:

```
    m_fapps.push_back(new fpp1(renderingEngine)); //fpp* are subclasses of fppVirtual
    m_fapps.push_back(new fpp2(renderingEngine));
    m_fapps.push_back(new fpp3(renderingEngine));
```

As `m_fapps` is a vector instance variable in another class, I want to make sure that class's destructor properly cleans up `m_fapps`:

```
       for (int i=0, size=m_fapps.size();i<size;++i){
        delete m_fapps[i];
       }
```

Is this acceptable memory management technique? I assume this loop is needed since when the vector goes out of scope when its owning class is destructed, only pointers to these `new` objects will be removed, right?

Comment: How is your vector declared?

Comment: Yes. But look into `std::unique_ptr` instead of doing this.

Comment: In the future, please post complete code examples. The answers to such questions are often more complex that one would think initially, and providing a complete example helps define the scope of a question (and the answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one gave you straight forward answer yet - yes, it is acceptable and this is the only way to free this memory, having this declaration of the `vector`.

This can and should be avoided, using smart pointers, as @OliCharlesworth suggested or using some other container, ponited by @BjörnPollex.

Comment: Thank you for actually providing an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This works (with a few caveats) but is not considered idiomatic C++, for good reason.

You should strongly consider using a vector of smart pointers (or a smart vector like `boost::ptr_vector`) instead, in order to avoid having to do manual memory management.

This would also give you exception safety for free, and would also avoid nasty ownership issues that occur if your outer class is copyable.

Comment: i'm inclined to agree with the other suggestion that `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` is a natural fit for this if I have no other reason to include boost in my project

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Once you look into Boost a bit more, I am sure you will find plenty of reasons to include it in your project.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: sure, there are now a number of smart pointer types in the standard library, pick the one that best suits your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead. The interface is the same, but it handles memory management for you. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3822612/160206) for some guidelines about whether to use `ptr_vector` or `vector<shared_ptr<>>`.

Comment: Or `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`, which is probably a better default choice, since there is no indication of shared ownership in OP's code.

Comment: Correct, I am still stuck on C++03.